# How webbrowser.open() works on Android?

Tags: python-3.x

I executed below python code using mobile app(IDE),and it worked.

But I am wondering how it opened the browser,without using any external tools like Appium.Is there any internal piece of code that understands the platform?

```
  import webbrowser
  webbrowser.open("https://google.com")
```